# How do I get my button to trigger my onchange event in my textinput box?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I want to have a button that triggers my onchange event inside my text input instead of when I click out of my text input it triggers the event. I want a button that triggers what is happening inside my text input instead of the text input triggering the event when I click outside of it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Select property of the button.

```
Select(InputText)
```